# Run UDF after others functions?

Tags: excel, vba, api, post, udf

I have a UDF that collects results of other functions and sends them to an web API which calculates and sends a response. e.g.

```
           A                      B                   C               D
7  =CalcResult(E7, F7)    =CalcResult(G7, H7)        234     =SendToAPI(A7,B7,C7)
8  =CalcResult(E8, F8)    =CalcResult(G8, H8)        274     =SendToAPI(A8,B8,C8)
9         ...                    ...                 ...             ...
```

What happens is that when you Run the SendtoAPI it Posts to the API twice one with 2 nulls and the value in c then the second with the correct data after the calcResult is finished.

Is there any way of ordering which gets called first?

Set the SendToAPI to run last?

Comment: Why not `=SendToAPI(CalcResult(E8, F8), CalcResult(G8, H8), C7)`? If C7 is a formula, stick that in there too.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but the client wants to see the results of those parts as they go through, e.g one of those could be calculating the number of days it takes for a package to deliver and that might be needed in another function.

Comment: Maybe you can check the validity of the arguments of the UDF SendToAPI at the start of the function and exit if one is Null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UDFs are often calculated more than once in the calculation sequence when they are called with not-yet-calculated parameters. An un-calculated variant parameter appears to the UDF as an empty variant: so the solution is to exit the UDF without sending to the web api if any of the parameters are empty.

See my website page http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsj.htm for more details

And my blog post https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/25/writing-efficient-vba-udfs-part-7-udfs-calculated-multiple-times/

Comment: Thanks very much, It took a lot of fiddling but the IsCalced function worked perfectly when variables where passed in as variants. Very useful Response and Great website with lots of tips. Will definitely recommend to others.